# SQL Injection jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, sql-injection

`select ID from USER where ID is not null order by ID`

Tenacity is throwing SQl injection as high vulnerability.

I tried to resolve as follows :

```java
String sql = "select ID from user where :id is not null order by ID";
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcNamesTpl = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.jdbcTemplate);
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("id", "ID");
jdbcNamesTpl.query(sql,parameters,mapper);
```

But I am getting all records along with null values. Anyone share thoughts or any suggestion to solve ?

Comment: How can a fixed SQL query (first one you show) be vulnerable to SQL injection? Or maybe I didn't understandwhar you're saying.

Comment: yes, first one is vulnerable to SQL injection. I tried by using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to solve SQL injection but its not giving correct results.

Comment: Parameterized statements fix SQL injection only if the query is actually generated dynamically, which your original query is not. So your code analysis tool appears to be wrong.

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using? In some SQL dialects, user and / or ID might be keywords. This could be related to the - presumably misleading - warning you are getting. You can escape identifiers that might be confused with keywords, but the exact syntax depends on the DBMS you are using. SQL Server: Square brackets (e.g.   `[user]`, `[ID]`); MySQL: Backticks (e.g. \`user\`,  \`ID\`), PostgreSQL: Double quotes (e.g. `"user"`, `"ID"`), ...

Comment: I updated the query with different table name and column  name here. I am using different table and column in my project

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be using the Spring [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) - as folks have pointed out, this seems to be using parameterized queries, which should be safe.

It's possible that Tenacity is getting confused because the named parameter is the same as the column - and it believes that you are using a named parameter in the order by clause (which would be a potential SQL injection).  Try changing the name of the parameter to something that's not a column name.